# Why does a code block not work inside a table?

Tags: formatting, asciidoc

I try to put some source code into a table using asciidoc. For whatever reason, I do not manage to put it well formated into a cell.

This is my test I use at https://asciidoclive.com for testing:

```
.The working version of the code (outside table)
....
/* define the types we need for the struct */
typedef void* (*open)();
typedef void (*updateNumber)(void*, int);
typedef void (*updateLabel)(void*, const char*);
typedef void (*close)(void*);
....

.Not working inside of a table
[options="header"]
|=======================
|function |getProperty

|example 1
|
....
/* define the types we need for the struct */
typedef void* (*open)();
typedef void (*updateNumber)(void*, int);
typedef void (*updateLabel)(void*, const char*);
typedef void (*close)(void*);
....

|example 2
|

`/* define the types we need for the struct */
typedef void* (*open)();
typedef void (*updateNumber)(void*, int);
typedef void (*updateLabel)(void*, const char*);
typedef void (*close)(void*);`

|=======================
```

I wanted to show more things I tried, but StackOverflow does not let me put in more code :-(

I tried with ++++, ----, .... and backticks. While the first three do not work at all, backticks are working somehow but do not work properly with the *pointers and interprets it as bold sometimes.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found it by fortune. The cell must be defined to render asciidoc content. Otherwise it only renders as reduced function set (only basic stuff working).

```
.Working inside of a table
[options="header", cols="1,4"]
|=======================
|function |getProperty

|example 1
a|
[source,C]
....
/* define the types we need for the struct */
typedef void* (*open)();
typedef void (*updateNumber)(void*, int);
typedef void (*updateLabel)(void*, const char*);
typedef void (*close)(void*);
....

|example 2
a|
[source,C]
----
/* define the types we need for the struct */
typedef void* (*open)();
typedef void (*updateNumber)(void*, int);
typedef void (*updateLabel)(void*, const char*);
typedef void (*close)(void*);
----
|=======================
```

Please note the **a|** instead of a simple **|** symbol used.

This is the page where it is explained in a good manner:

https://blog.mrhaki.com/2014/11/awesome-asciidoctor-styling-columns-and.html